# Typescript initialise a type with initial/ default value

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to create a `Type` with value in it.

eg:

```
type Animal = {
    kind : "animal"
    Legs : number,
    CanFly: boolean
}

const monkey: Animal = { Legs: 4, CanFly: false};  //In this line, clients has to initialize the same value `kind : "animal"`
```

I would to create an attribute called kind and use that to infer the object and make decisions.
However, in the next line, i would expect the clients to pass the same value back in all the initializations. Otherwisem TS compiler would complain `Property 'kind' is missing in type'.

Is there a way to default it without the clients have to pass it back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a factory method:

```js
type Animal = {
    kind : "animal"
    Legs : number,
    CanFly: boolean
}

function createAnimal(parameter: Omit<Animal, 'kind'>): Animal {
    return {
        kind: 'animal',
        ...parameter,
    };
}

const monkey = createAnimal({ Legs: 4, CanFly: false});
```

Answer (score 4):

TypeScript is a structurally-typed language. Meaning when you defined a `type` or `interface` you defined a shape other objects must conform to. And assigning defaults within TS types is not possible.

```
type Animal = {
  kind : "animal"
  Legs : number,
  CanFly: boolean
}
```

I assume you are on a recent version of TS since your `kind` is a string literal type, "animal", and it can only ever be that string literal. And you have to supply `kind: "animal"` when you create objects of `Animal` shape.

Now, if you want to implement discriminated unions, you might choose the following approach (perhaps animal is a little to generic in this case):

```
type Snake = {
  kind: "snake"
  Legs : number,
  CanFly: boolean
}

type Dolphin = {
  kind: "dolphin",
  Legs: number,
  CanFly: boolean
}

type Monkey = {
  kind: "monkey",
  Legs: number,
  CanFly: boolean
}
```

Then a discriminated union:

```
type Animal = Snake | Dolphin | Monkey
```

To reiterate, TS does not support defaults in a type declaration. TS types define the shapes of things and if an object, *O*, doesn't conform to a shape, *T*, well then *O* is not a *T*.

Comment: if an object, O, doesn't conform to a shape, T, well then O is not a T
----
Is there an out of the box function or technique that figures out if O is of shape T.. rather than handcrafting inspection of each attribute of T agains O ?

Comment: There's no function to do this but this is one application of discriminated unions, using the value of `kind`, the discriminant, you can easily determine if an object is T. For example, if you want to check if an object, O, is `Monkey` then we use `if (O.kind === 'monkey') { // do monkey stuff }`

Comment: This isn't quite correct. While TypeScript is structurally typed, this is not the reason why types do not allow specifying default values or have any runtime effect. The language could be nominally typed and have the same emit restriction or structuray typed and have types that generate code.

Answer (score 3):

well you use a class instead of an object literal:

```js
export interface Animal {
    kind: string;
     Legs : number;
     CanFly: boolean;
   }
   
   export class AnimalDto implements Animal {
       kind: string;
       Legs : number;
       CanFly: boolean;

       static of () {
          return new AnimalDto({});
       }
   
       public constructor (animal: Partial<Animal>) {
          this.kind = animal.kind || "default value";
          this.Legs= animal.Legs || -1;
          this.CanFly = animal.CanFly || false;
       }
   }

const dog = AnimalDto.of();

const cat = new AnimalDto({kind: "domestic", Legs: 4, CanFly: false});
```